# Some activities load more difficult than others with my navigation drawer

Tags: android, load, navigation-drawer

I have an app that connects my activities with a navigation drawer.The problem is that some activities load more difficult than others(when i press the icon on drawer,instead of opens the activity immediately,it stays for 1-2 seconds and then loads the activity). It might be a dummy question but is it possible if you could give me some advice on how to fix it?Here is one of the activities that load more difficult

```
public class ImportAPI extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
public TextView fullnameside, emailside;

public static String stravaToken;

public ImageButton btnStrava;
public ImageView tickStrava;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.importapi);


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    toolbar.setTitle("");
    toolbar.setSubtitle("");

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    fullnameside = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.fullnameside);
    emailside = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.emailside);
    fullnameside.setText(""+GetInfo.fullname);
    emailside.setText(""+GetInfo.email);

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(3).setChecked(true);


    //STRAVA
    tickStrava=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tickStrava);
    btnStrava=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.stravaBtn);
    connectStrava();

}

public void connectStrava(){

    btnStrava.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent getStravaApi= new Intent(ImportAPI.this,StravaSetupApi.class);
            startActivity(getStravaApi);

        }

    });

    //GET ACCESS TOKEN FROM STRAVAS AUTHORIZE ACCOUNT
    String accessToken = StravaAuthenticateActivity.getStravaAccessToken(this);
    stravaToken=accessToken; //make static var so i can use it anywhere i want

    //Get athletes activities from GetStravaAthleteActivities.java
    new GetStravaAthleteActivities.AthleteActivities();

    //check if token is null so i can display the tick and also disable the button press
    if(stravaToken!=null)
    {
        btnStrava.setEnabled(false);
        tickStrava.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        tickStrava.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking whether it's the Activity's fault and not the drawer menu's. You could time your onnectStrava() method, which could be causing the delay. Add log messages at the beginning and the end of the method.

```
public void connectStrava(){
Log.d(“TAG”, “STRAVA Entry point);
…
Log.d(“TAG”, “STRAVA Exit point);
}
```

then check the timestamps on your IDE Logcat and see how long it takes for the method to run. if it's indeed 1-2 seconds, then you know what causes the delay. If that's the case you could try to start the method on a separate thread or as an AsyncTask, so as to not have the method block your UI

Comment: Thank you!I will implement the AsycnTask